# siunitx: scientific notation

Tags: math-mode, units, siunitx

I want to use scientific notation with the `siunitx` package.  However, when I try to do it I am getting  an error:

```
The width of a human hair is \SI{1 \times 10^{-4}}{m}.
```

This has always given me a LaTeX Error" `invalid character '10^{-4}' in numerical input`

Is there a better way to do this while continuing to use `siunitx`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it is output that's important here or the input?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question means.  I pulled the error string directly from the output generated from building the LaTeX document.

Comment: I wonder if you need `\SI{1 \times 10^{-4}}{m}` to work in the input or only to get `1 \times 10^{-4}` in the output.

Comment: Definitely the output.  I can provide whatever input to siunitx that is necessary to make scientific notation come out nicely.  Thanks!

Comment: @dtlussier regarding numbers without a unit:
`\SI{1e-4}` without any unit works. It will display like the tex `1 \times 10^{-4}` If your numbers don't have a unit there is also a nice tip here: that [defines a command \e](http://www.tapdancinggoats.com/easy-scientific-notation-in-latex.htm): `\providecommand{\e}(http://www.tapdancinggoats.com/easy-scientific-notation-in-latex.htm){\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}` so that you can use `1\e{-4}`.

Comment: @user766308 If you want to typeset a number without a unit, `siunitx` provides the `\num` command, e.g. `\num{e-4}` will print 10^{-4}.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Sure: `\SI{1e-4}{\metre}`.

Comment: Ok - thanks.  What about a number like `10^{-4}` that isn't scientific notation but has an exponent?

Comment: `\SI{e4}{\metre}`

Comment: @Joseph: That assumes a base of `10`. What about other bases, like `3^{5}`?

Comment: @Kit. `\sisetup{exponent-base = <whatever>}` using the current release (v2) of `siunitx`, or `\sisetup{expbase = <whatever>}` with v1.

Comment: Is there a way to force siunitx to use scientific notation even if the number is specific like with a decimal place?  Or is this outside the scope of the package?

Comment: @hertzsprung after a quick look at the manual, try  `scientific-notation=true`.

Comment: Is there a reason why `\SI{e4}{}` works, but not `\si{e4}`?

Comment: @anderstood Yes, the latter doesn't make sense. `\si` is for writing just a unit, 10^4 is a number. If you want just the number, use `\num{e4}`.