# Exponent like 2^3 in \SI

Tags: siunitx

How can I write an exponent in a `\SI` command like this:

```
\SI{2^3}{m}
```

The reason why I want to write `2^3` instead of `8` is that I have a formula above saying `b^3` and I want to show the calculation steps very detailed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [siunitx: scientific notation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/siunitx-scientific-notation)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Assuming `b = 2m` then what you want is `$(\SI{2}{\metre})^3 = \SI{8}{\cubic\metre}$` because also the unit needs the exponent, right!?

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: I did not close the vote :-)

Answer (score 18):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{2^3}{m}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. :-) Two additional possibilities: `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{2\cubed}{m}` and `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{2\tothe3}{m}`.